# How can I reindex a particular index or table without SSH?

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

I need to reindex some tables, like `catalog_product_flat` Or whatever else, I don't have `ssh` access to my host, & I have to do it with Scheduler or something.
I checked so many answers, but I couldn't get them.
I'm using magento 1.9.2
Please help me!

**EDIT:**
How should I fill this?

Is it enough?
[image]

Comment: if you have admin access then you can reindex using `system >> Index management` section

Comment: this doesn't work for catalog_product_flat

Answer (score 0):

```
  0 6 * * * php -f /shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

you can set cron with this one for reindex. set time as you want for cron.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the re-index with php script. This is the one of the way for reindex the magento index.

```
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
       $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
       $process->reindexAll();
 }
```

I just got reference from here. You can follow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827996/magento-reindexing-price-programmatically).

Comment: I need to use a scheduler, I can't reindex everything  each time.

Comment: If you have cpanel than you need to create 1 file on magento root directory and write above code and include the require code to run that file like (incluse app.php , set store etc...) and than set that file in cron job in cpanel at the time distance you want to run that file:


*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php YOUR FILE PATH/FILE.php

Please see this link for set cron job in cpanel: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9453/29/how-to-run-scripts-via-cron-jobs